# CrossTable output to excel in R

Tags: r, excel, contingency

When producing contingency tables I'm using the function `CrossTable` in R because it is the most informative and flexible that I have managed to find, and it gives you a lot of stuff right away without the need to calculate it seperately.
However, the ouput it generates is a text output that is aimed mainly for the console in R. This is a big problem for me because I'm relying on outputing these kind of tables to excel at the next step of the analysis.

Is there any way to output the `CrossTable` output to an Excel spreadsheet so that each number will be in its own cell? (i.e., not as text that goes entirely to a single cell) ("text to columns" does not help)

Comment: Hi, please specify the package `CrossTable` belongs to. And reproducible example of what you are trying to achieve would be great.

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot that. The package is `gmodels`. A reproducible example is not necessary because I ask about any output it gives. All I want is to be able to output it to Excel in a way that will allow me to edit it later, as opposed to pasting the information as text in excel (and then have all the information in one cell)

Comment: @Corel if you are using RStudio you can use `View()` and then just copy-paste the output from the RStudio View window

Comment: @MikolajM View() does not give me anything when using it with CrossTable. It just opens a blank tab. CrossTable basically returns a list in a nice formatted look in the console.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a function that turns the crosstable into an excel file. Maybe it'll be usefull to someone else too:

```
#writes output from gmodels::CrossTable to an excel file
#package "xlsx" should be installed
crossExcel <- function(Cross.Table, file, chi=F) {  
  Cross.Table <- x
  
  t <- reshape(as.data.frame(Cross.Table[["t"]]), idvar="x", timevar="y", direction="wide")
  row <- reshape(as.data.frame(Cross.Table[["prop.row"]]), idvar="x", timevar="y", direction="wide")
  col <- reshape(as.data.frame(Cross.Table[["prop.col"]]), idvar="x", timevar="y", direction="wide")
  tbl <- reshape(as.data.frame(Cross.Table[["prop.tbl"]]), idvar="x", timevar="y", direction="wide")
  
  xlsx::write.xlsx(t, file=file, sheetName="t", row.names=F)
  xlsx::write.xlsx(row, file=file, sheetName="prop.row", append=T, row.names=F)
  xlsx::write.xlsx(col, file=file, sheetName="prop.col", append=T, row.names=F)
  xlsx::write.xlsx(tbl, file=file, sheetName="prop.tbl", append=T, row.names=F)
  
  if (chi==T) {
    exp <- as.data.frame(x[["chisq"]][["expected"]])
    xlsx::write.xlsx(exp, file=file, sheetName="exp", append=T, row.names=T)
    
    t <- t[ ,2:3]
    chip <- ((exp-t)*(exp-t))/exp
    xlsx::write.xlsx(chip, file=file, sheetName="prop.chisq", append=T, row.names=T)
  }
  
  print(paste0("CrossTable exported to ", getwd() ,file))
}
```

Example of how it's used:

```
data(infert, package = "datasets") #obtaining exapmle data
x <- gmodels::CrossTable(infert$education, infert$induced) 
crossExcel(x, "output.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# obtaining data
library('gmodels')
data(infert, package = "datasets")
# asign the result to object
d <- CrossTable(infert$education, infert$induced, expected = TRUE)
# now you can use d object to build something you could save using
# `write.table` to csv or directly to xlsx by other methods

# use str(d) to study structure of returned object
str(d)
```